# OperationalError at /admin/ no such table: django_session

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I encountered a problem in my Django project, which I thought was from the database, but when I deleted it and entered the command `python.exe .\manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, but when the command `python manage.py migrate`, everything went well except for one thing

the problem:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK       
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0013_remove_user_id_alter_user_username...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 324, in execute
    return super().execute(query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "auth_user_groups" referencing "auth_user"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\shop\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\shop\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle        
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards   
    state = self.apply_migration(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration
    with self.connection.schema_editor(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 244, in check_constraints     
    violations = cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check").fetchall()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers        
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 324, in execute
    return super().execute(query)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "auth_user_groups" referencing "auth_user"
```

The problems didn't end here, I couldn't request any pages

If I make a request to the admin page, this will happen:
[See the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBkie.png)

Or if I make a request to the main page, this will happen:
[See the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoxHs.png)

I really don't know what to do

Comment: I'm confused about what your actual error is.  The post title refers to `OperationalError at /admin/ no such table: django_session`, but the error traceback message in the post does not mention that error at all.  So what is the actual error?